# Generic function restriction

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
type ID = { id: number };
type NAME = { name: string };
type Primary<T> = T extends ID ? number : never;

function idOf<T extends ID & NAME>(p: T): Primary<T> {
  return p.id;   // <----- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Primary<T>'.ts(2322)

}
```

How can I restrict `T` in `idOf` in such a way that it cannot violate the constraints imposed by `ID`, i.e. `id` must be `number` in any specialised type.

The point is: `T extends ID`, so `Primary<T>` must be `number`.

Comment: There is no `foo` at all

Comment: I meant `idOf`. sorry...

Comment: why don't you just remove the return-type? `p.id` will for sure be a number, so the return type of the function will also be a number.. [Stackblitz](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIlAvFA3lAlgEwFxQHYCuAtgEYQBOUAvgNwBQokUAcgIICyAokqvgIZEIuAM7By6PAHNq9RtAAK4on3IgAPABUAfDw1QIAD2AQ8mYbAQB+fMTKVceCADcK9OgDMCeAMbB0AezwMTAB5d019IxMzCygAMhYOTi0ACjBcDQBKKFQ6HJzyCGACciCwADoseiogA)